# Why is switching the quotation marks necessary for certain cases in Powershell on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell

Yesterday, I was trying to use [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to rewrite my project's Git history and update the author/committer details with the following command.

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback '
  old_email = b"email@example.com"
  old_email2 = b"email@example.com"
  correct_name = b"FirstName LastName"
  correct_email = b"email@example.com"
  
  if commit.committer_email == old_email or commit.committer_email == old_email2:
    commit.committer_name = correct_name
    commit.committer_email = correct_email

  if commit.author_email == old_email or commit.author_email == old_email2: 
    commit.author_name = correct_name
    commit.author_email = correct_email
  '
```

The problem is that this would work if I had no spaces in any of the strings declared, e.g. in the `correct_name`'s value. But otherwise, it would give me a `Unknown argument: LastName` error.

Searching around I came across this [5 years old post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37473136/14822928) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37475224/14822928) to it, which suggested to switch the quotation marks from single to double and vice-versa.

Strangely though, that worked perfectly. What I don't understand is why so?

According to that post's OP, it's some kind of a bug in Powershell. However, I am using the latest cross-platform `Powershell v7.2.3`.

---

#### Edit

As pointed out in the comments the quotation marks affect how a string is parsed by the shell.

According to the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2),

> A string enclosed in single quotation marks is a verbatim string.

However as seen above, I am, in fact, using single quotes and still encountering some parsing issue. As soon as the outer quotes are changed to double quotes and the inner ones to single, the command *works*.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with the Console Host nor the terminal; that's not where command parsing happens. I'm guessing (don't have PWSH 7 here yet) that it's related to PWSH parsing and rebuilding the command line in the wrong way (Windows programs don't receive an argv array) and remember seeing a few GitHub issues related to that topic ... Will test this sometime later.

Comment: Is the error from Powershell or from git filter-repo?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio the error's from `git filter-repo`

Comment: @cryptic Sometimes with PowerShell you have to use single quotes around values if that value will be used for a command and passed parameters if the command that executes the parameters scream like a long string value with spaces also needs to be one value including the spaces  (e.g. `"-param1 valuecool -param2 Value too cool"` may need to be built as `'-param1 valuecool -param2 "Value too cool"'`) a good example is `Start-Process` and it's `-ArgumentList` parameters values. Not sure if that helps any or not, but something I wanted to share at a minimum with you otherwise.

Comment: @cryptic So where to you have `correct_name = b"FirstName LastName"` and then you use `commit.committer_name = correct_name` you may need to ensure that that variable also is double or single quoted if it's stripped implicitly so maybe use something like `commit.committer_name = "correct_name"` or `commit.committer_name = 'correct_name'`, You are wanting it to be one big string to set for `commit.committer_name` but it thinks it is two separate values and parameter rather than just one I think. So maybe something to test with using single quotes in the initial values not 100% certain though.

Comment: you may find it a tad more reliable to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet and explicitly specify the various arguments.

Comment: The purpose of single and double quotes are pretty well documented. What research have you done prior to asking here?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Thank you for suggesting the use of `Start-Process` and the link to the PowerShell documentation (I couldn't find it). It seems that since double quoted strings are _expandable_ in PS, it's just parsing it wrong.  And since single quote strings are parsed as _literal_ strings, it solves the issue.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle could you write this as an answer so that I can accept the answer and this question appears closed. Otherwise, I would write it myself :)